# RegEx pattern to remove string between two specific characters

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I am cleaning some HTML strings and would like to remove empty spaces between > and < characters.

This is an example of my string:

```
<h4>Specifications</h4>    <table>  <tr>  <td>Brand</td>    <td>Dell</td>    </tr>  </table>
```

I would like to remove those X empty spaces between html tags.

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) and show us what you have tried so far. Then ask a *specific* question to the code you have tried.

Comment: Quick solution: Trim function or clean

Comment: start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

Comment: @Sgdva, trim will not clear spaces inside a string, only leading and trailing

Comment: @avb You're right, my bad. He can use substitute " " for "".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty straight-forward:

```
>\s+<
# match >
# 1+ whitespaces
# <
```

This needs to be replaced by `><`, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/7Pl5Y2/1/).